# Error:(20, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I  have  looked  at other  related but none  seems to Solve  my   Problem in Gradle.

Here is  my  Build Gradle (Module  App )

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.abdul_000.project"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}



// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to     all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
      repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
    dependencies {




        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



    } apply plugin: 'application'
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
   }
  }
```

The are it  gives  me 
"Error:(20, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:The project 'Project' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Open Gradle wrapper file
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin"

What  am I  doing  wrong  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add compile dependencies to **global** `build.gradle` file. Removing the second dependencies block in your **global** `build.gradle` file would fix the error.